# What does \rmfamily do, or how do I undo a declaration like \em and \bfseries?

Tags: emphasis, declare

The short example below shows that `\bfseries` has its effect, but that is superimposed on `\em`'s effect. If `\rmfamily` just means "don't add anything", that also explains why it has fundamentally no effect. However, I curious to know if there is an `\un-em`/`\remove-previous-declarations` declaration or something

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Hello, \em my name \bfseries is Enrico. \rmfamily And now what?
\end{document}
```

I know I can limit the emphasized text by using the `\emph` command instead of the `\em` declaration, but I'm curious to know.

Comment: `\rmfamily` changes the font to the serif family as opposed to the sans serif. You can enclose the text in `{}` to make the font change local.

Comment: `\em` is not a font change it is _emphasis_  try `\em one \em two`

Comment: `\rmfamily` switches to the roman family, to see it have an effect put `\sffamily`  before `Hello` so it is all sans serif up to that point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\emreset` to cancel the effect of `\em` and `normalfont` or `\mdseries` to cancel the effect of `\bfseries`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, \em my name \emreset\bfseries is Enrico. \normalfont And now what?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use `{}` to limit the effective scope.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, {\em my name} {\bfseries is Enrico.} And now what?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or just use TextFontCommand with parameter.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, \emph{my name} \textbf{is Enrico.} And now what?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The action of `\rmfamily` isn't “do nothing”.

In the NFSS model, adopted by LaTeX around 1994, fonts are characterized by four independent attributes:

1. encoding
2. family
3. shape
4. series

to which we might add the size. These attributes are independent of each other. The encoding is a bit peculiar and I'll not deal with it.

There are some predefined commands that change one attribute at a time:

- `\rmfamily`, `\sffamily`, `\ttfamily`
- `\upshape`, `\itshape`, `\scshape`, `\slshape`
- `\mdseries`, `\bfseries`

Font packages that support richer fonts may define other commands for shapes and series.

There's also another “abstract” declaration, namely `\em`, that used to be defined as “if the current font is not slanted, do `\itshape`, otherwise do `\upshape`. The meaning was recently changed to support a series of commands, to the effect of being able to specify differently what “emphasis inside emphasis” is realized. Let's not complicate things, as your example is easy.

Assuming you start off with `\normalfont`, you get

> Hello, <rmfamily/itshape/mdseries>my name <rmfamily/itshape/bfseries>is Enrico. <rmfamily/itshape/bfseries>And now what?

The last `\rmfamily` command does nothing, because the family was already `\rmfamily`: you never changed the family, did you?

There is no command that “undoes the last change”, because this doesn't make sense in the NFSS model: the commands listed above should never be used in the document, unless they're *inside a group*. By general rule of TeX, a group limits the scope of a font selection, so when you do something like

```
{\em text}
```

the font choice performed by `\em` disappears and the font returns to be the one in force when the group started.

Generally, I prefer `\itshape text` if I want italics in an alignment cell, because `\textit{text}` would make LaTeX spinning some more wheels for no gain.

Yes! The commands listed above have a command-with-argument counterpart:

- `\textrm`, `\textsf`, `\texttt`
- `\textup`, `\textit`, `\textsc`, `\textsl`
- `\textmd`, `\textbf`
- `\emph`

The last one is “abstract” and the font it chooses depends on the context, just like `\em`. Such commands *are to be preferred* to change font in running text: use `\emph{my name is Enrico}` rather than `{\em my ...}`, because `\emph` also takes care of the italic correction that might be needed before or after the font change.

What do you do if you want that emphasis inside emphasis is realized as upshape boldface? You declare in the document preamble something like

```
\DeclareEmphSequence{\itshape,\upshape\bfseries,\itshape\bfseries}
```

Example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareEmphSequence{\itshape,\upshape\bfseries,\itshape\bfseries}

\begin{document}

Hello, \emph{my name \emph{is Enrico.}} And now what?

\emph{Hello, \emph{my name \emph{is Enrico.} And} now} what?

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second (contrived) example, you see that the attributes are reverted one by one as the various nested groups end.